# What's the best way to migrate DynamoDB tables data when using CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk

We already have our infra deployed on AWS and now we're introducing IaC using AWS CDK. One of the goals of this migration is to handle our database (DynamoDB) changes without or having a minimum downtime as possible and preserve the database data from the previous infra version.

As mentioned on the CDK best practices page we should *Use generated resource names, not physical names* but it implies destroying the database tables instead of changing it every time we need to change something, right? And then how can we migrate the data from the old table to the new one reliable and with minimum downtime (preferable zero down-time)?

DMS (Database Migration Service) looks like the best approach but I'm wondering what and how you guys are handling this requirement.

Reference
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/best-practices-for-developing-cloud-applications-with-aws-cdk/

Comment: `it implies destroying the database tables instead of changing it every time we need to change something, right` no. It means that for a change that *requires* resource replacement, the update will fail with a user-specified physical name, because CloudFormation will be unable to create a copy with the same name. The resource is recreated in any case (if a change requires replacement). This is not a CDK issue.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to import DynamoDB table into CloudFormation using [CloudFormation import feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html), and then retroactively model it in CDK, making sure that logical ID of resource matched the one in CloudFormation after import. You can overwrite logical ID in CDK using `overrideLogicalId` method of the [CfnResourse](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_core.CfnResource.html) construct.

This way your table remains in place and no migration is needed.